# Dynamically show or hide table in jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports

I am facing problem to show or hide the table in Jasper Report.

When no data are available then it's show a horizontal line.

I want to hide the static text field and table from report when the query retrieves no data.

Can anyone help me?

Here I have attached my output.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try setting a Print When expression for the static text and also for each column of the table.

Here's an example of how it could look:

```
// determine somewhere whether the received table data is empty or not.
// save the result as a boolean and add it to report parameters
boolean ifTableEmpty = false;  // for example
parameters.put("ifTableEmpty", ifTableEmpty);

// create a Print When expression
JRDesignExpression whenToPrintTheTable = new JRDesignExpression();
whenToPrintTheTable.setText("$P{ifTableEmpty}");    

// add the expression to your static text and similarly for each column
staticText.setPrintWhenExpression(whenToPrintTheTable);
```

Comment: sorry i am beginer to the jasper report, can you tell me how to iterate the table data? Give me some example code.

Comment: Hmm. If you're asking that question, then I'm guessing that the data is read _after_ you create the Jasper Design object. Iterating through every column of the data would be an unnecessary complication, then. (It's a bit hard to find the right suggestions without seeing any of your code, you know.) Now I'm thinking that it should be enough to check if you get any data _before_ creating the table, and just not creating it if the data is empty. I can't provide any example code, because I don't know how you get the data.

Comment: In my jasper report i designed the table object and fill the table with query. In my case, Is it possible to hide the table.

Comment: If you can get the query data _first_, then design the table object, and then fill the table, then yes.

Comment: Thank you, it's working for me. but right now i am facing another problem. In my report i have several tables, when some of tables hidden (because of there is no data), then also some other tables are printed on another page instead of first page. i given position type as float to every tables. Can you help me?

Comment: Glad to hear it works :) I am guessing that right now you are still adding the table to the report even if there is no data, but you are not filling it. If that is the case, you could try not adding the table to the report or even not creating it when there is no data for it (in short, putting all the code for creating the table inside the `if (!ifTableEmpty)` statement). Another thing is, sometimes things are printed on new pages if elements on the page exceed available page height (without header and footer) - you could look into that, too.

Comment: Right now i am created report using ireport netbeans plugin, here how can i do that one?

Comment: Hmm, I don't think you can. 
I'd try setting the height of table elements to zero, then.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a subreport, content will be the code you want to show or hide.
After that use Print When expression on any retrieving field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the No Data section. That is designed to handle the layout in case no data is returned by the query. You can find No Data as the last but one section - above Background and below Summary